# how to fix my control number problem im using trigger

Tags: sql, triggers

Good day every one this is my trigger code that after the user will insert a data and select a pr date it will generate a control number in the database but my problem here is when the user pick a pr_date that is 01-28-2021 and after adding record it display a value in the datatabase 202103-1 it must display a value of 202101-1

```
 BEGIN
      SET @v1 = (SELECT control_number FROM tbl_worklog where DATE_FORMAT(pr_date,'%Y%m') =DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
      IF (@v1 is null) THEN 
         SET new.control_number = (CONCAT(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m') as CHAR),"-1"));
      ELSE 
         SET @v2 = (CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@v1,"-",-1) as int)+1);
         SET new.control_number = (CONCAT(CAST(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m') as CHAR),"-",CAST(@v2 as char)));
      END IF;
      

END
```

Comment: This is clearly not PHP. It would help if you added the flavour of SQL that you're using. Please update the tags accordingly

Comment: SQL Trigger code depends on the database.  Your question requires a database tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the control number, you're using the formula

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y%m')
```

which will look at the current date, which is why you're getting `202103` (it's currently March, the third month). You should instead use

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(pr_date, '%Y%m')
```